# How to omit using python coverage lib?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I would like to omit some module that are in some particular directory : eggs and bin

```
coverage -r -i --omit=/usr/lib/,/usr/share/,eggs,bin
Name                                                                 Stmts   Exec  Cover
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bin/test                                                                5      5   100%
eggs/BeautifulSoup-3.0.7a-py2.6.egg/BeautifulSoup                    1008    463     45%
eggs/Django-1.0.2_final-py2.6.egg/django/__init__                      15     12    80%
```

I have also try several variant of this without luck :

```
coverage -r -i --omit=/usr/lib/,/usr/share/,`pwd`/eggs,`pwd`/bin
or
coverage -r -i --omit=/usr/lib/,/usr/share/,django,BeautifulSoup
or 
coverage -r -i --omit=/usr/lib/,/usr/share/,<absolute path>/eggs
```

It would be great if someone has a tip to get this working.

Answer (score 6):

To tell you the truth, I think this might just be a bug in coverage.py.  I'll look into it soon.

UPDATED: OK, I've fixed this bug (I hope), and posted new kits: [Coverage.py 3.2b2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage/3.2b2).  Please let me know if it still is no good.

Comment: To tell you the truth I am almost positive it is one I have been trying to identify the root cause in coverage without success.
I would be glad that you bit me at it  :-)
Thank you for this lib.
Regards,
--yml

Comment: I don't know if it is a side effect of some other application running at the moment on my computer I did easy_install -U coverage. The package has been updated but it seems significantly slower and I it is right now eating almost 3 GB of ram.

Comment: I'm still unable to use the omit flag. Anyone else?